# Convert Unicode characters to hex causes extra bytes

Tags: javascript, unicode, hex

Here is the code that I use for escaping muti-bytes unicode characters.

```
let sample = '1F3C4-1F3FB-200D-2640-FE0F'; //‍♀️
let characters = String.fromCodePoint(...sample.split('-').map(code => parseInt(code, 16)));
let codes = '';
for(let i=0;i<characters.length;i++){
    codes += (i === 0 ? '' : '-') + characters.codePointAt(i).toString(16).toUpperCase();
}
console.log(codes); //1F3C4-DFC4-1F3FB-DFFB-200D-2640-FE0F
```

As you can see from the example, the conversion causes 2 extra bytes in the result.

Is there anything wrong with my code? How can I fix it?

Comment: Should `str` in your code be `characters` instead?

Comment: @Frxstrem My bad. I've fixed it. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the `codePointAt` function gives "a number representing the code unit value of the character at the given index". However, the index is the same as for `charCodeAt`, so if that index is in the middle of a surrogate pair (such as `\uD83C\uDFC4` for `\u{1F3C4}`), it will only give the second half of the surrogate pair.

You can see this in your output, since the extra characters appear right after the two characters with surrogate pairs (`U+1xxxx` characters) and that they are the second half of their preceding surrogate pair.

If you are using ES6, you can use the spread operator to split the unicode characters (while not splitting the surrogate pairs, like `string.split()` does):

```js
const string = "\u{1F3C4}\u{1F3FB}\u200D\u2640\uFE0F";
console.log(string); // ‍♀️

const codes = [ ...string ].map(ch =>
  ch.codePointAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase()
).join('-');
console.log(codes); // 1F3C4-1F3FB-200D-2640-FE0F
```

Comment: May I ask, why does the spread operator correctly split the surrogate pairs while the other methods don't?

Comment: @Tresdin Because JavaScript has only recently added features that support proper handling of surrogate pairs (such as `.codePointAt()` or the spread operator); `split()` and other, older methods don't support it because of backwards compatabiliy (e.g., changing the behavior of these functions *will* break some applications that rely on it). That's also why there are two functions, `codePointAt` and `chatCodeAt`, that seemingly does the same job.

Comment: I think I've learnt something new today. Big thanks for both your answer and the bonus explanation.